# argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter type "int **"

Tags: c++

I'm writing a 2d array program and i'm having issues getting it to print out, I'm not sure if i'm doing my 2d array passing correct now as its crashing instead of running at all.  Any advice would be helpful

```
void initialize(int* one, int** two);
void replace(int* arr,int rows, int cols,int value);
void fill(int* arr, int rows, int cols);
void print(int** arr, int rows, int cols);

ofstream outfile;
ifstream infile;
int arrayOne[100][100];
int arrayTwo[100][100];

int main(){

    int rows,cols=0;

    cout << "Please input how many rows you would like in the array:  ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Please input how many columns you would like in the array:  ";
    cin >> cols;

    fill(arrayOne[100][100],rows,cols);
    //print(arrayOne[100][100],rows,cols);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void initialize(int* one, int* two){
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
            arrayOne[i][j]=0;
            arrayTwo[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

void replace(int* arr,int rows,int cols,int value){
    arr[rows][cols]=value;
}

void fill(int* arr, int rows, int cols){
    int i=0;
    for(int r=0; r < rows; r++){
        for(int c=0; c < cols; c++){
            replace(arr,r,c,i++);
        }
    }
}

void print(int** arr, int r, int c){
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: With all the pointer masturbation, this looks awfully like C instead of C++!

Comment: An array is not the same as a pointer. That's your one wrong assumption leading to a lot of problems. Just use vectors, will you?

Comment: Post all of your errors and add line numbers in comments.

Comment: For anyone wondering where the problem is, `fill(arrayOne[100][100],rows,cols);`.

Comment: > pointer masturbation. I love the expression.

Comment: @chris: there are about 5 other problems, such as doubly subscripting an `int *`.

Comment: And passing arguments that aren't used anywhere in function body (initialize()).

Comment: By the way, [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Comment: @Wug, Yes, I picked out the first line the compiler gave that error on. I presumed there were others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error message, it plainly states your problem. That being said, it does not plainly state how to fix it. You're going down a rough path with fixed arrays...

```
/* arrayOne[100][100] This is an 'int' at the 101st row and 101st column.
 * It isn't an address to anywhere in the array, in fact it is just beyond
 * the end of your array.
 *
 * Regardless, even if it were a pointer, it would point to a location in memory
 * that is not yours. We count starting with 0 in C/C++. So if you'd like to
 * reference the 'whole' array  just pass it bare:
 */
fill (arrayOne, rows, cols);

/* Of course this means that you need to fix the definition of 'fill'
 * and 'replace'.
 */
void replace(int arr[100][100],int rows,int cols,int value){
    arr[rows][cols]=value;
}

/* As you can see this isn't going to be friendly */
void fill(int arr[100][100], int rows, int cols){
    int i=0;
    for(int r=0; r < rows; r++){
        for(int c=0; c < cols; c++){
            replace(arr,r,c,i++);
        }
    }
}
```

You have other issues, but those can be asked in other questions when you run into them.

Comment: Yea I completely screwed up my 2D array. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change all int* arr and int** arr to int arr[100][] or to arr[][100]. I don't remember which one. but, it's one of them for sure.

Comment: I used to use Microsoft Visual Studio 6 compiler. and I am sure you can do this.